# xpath 2.0 - How do you calculate the sum of calculated values?

Tags: xml, xpath, sum, xpath-2.0

[CLM Doc Gen High-Level Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OzBD.jpg)Sample of my xml, below.  For each 'Part' Nodeset, I am multiplying Cost by Qty (Cost * Qty).  That works just fine at the nodeset level.  I am trying to SUM all the (Cost * Qty) and put the TOTAL at the bottom of my document.

I'm restricted to xpath 2.0 (cannot use xslt functions).  Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

```
<AddPart_Container displayName="Add Sensor(s)" displayValue="Add Sensor(s)">
    <Part displayName="Part (Sensor 02)" displayValue="Part (Sensor 02)">
        <PartCategory>Hardware</PartCategory>
        <PartName>Wireless Enterprise Vibration Sensor V3 (1 MP per)</PartName>
        <PartNumber>PR55-61E</PartNumber>
        <Cost>366.95</Cost>
        <DirectPrice>492.95</DirectPrice>
        <Qty>200</Qty>
    </Part>
    <Part displayName="Part (Sensor 04)" displayValue="Part (Sensor 04)">
        <PartCategory>Hardware</PartCategory>
        <PartName>Wireless 3 Channel Current Sensor - 0 to 100 (3 MP per)</PartName>
        <PartNumber>PR55-26C</PartNumber>
        <Cost>337.94</Cost>
        <DirectPrice>492.95</DirectPrice>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
    </Part>
</AddPart_Container>
```

Below works just fine for each node (there is unique syntax for the program i am using).  Now I just need to Sum for all the nodesets and am really struggling since I'm summing this calculated field.

```
<# <Content Select="round((./DirectPrice * ./Qty div 12) * 100) div 100"/> #>
```

Comment: Hey NikkiC! Just a quick note to say that you should generally use backtick characters to enclose any code in your questions, otherwise it can easily be misinterpreted by StackOverflow. Your example expression was invisible (!) but I edited the question to add backticks around it, and now we can see it. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Thank you, Conal, new at this!

Comment: Hey NikkiC!  Actually no `for` expression is needed. There is a way to directly express the needed computation.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a [`for` expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions) to iterate through all the `Part` elements and return the calculated result for each `Part`, producing a sequence of numeric values. Then you can use the [XPath `sum` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-sum) to sum the numbers in that sequence. Something like this:

```xpath
sum(
   for $part in 
      //Part 
   return
      round(($part/DirectPrice * $part/Qty div 12) * 100) div 100
)
```

Result: `8626.62`

Comment: Something challenging to add.  I am using DocuSign CLM.  Its a 'Document Generator' tool that that takes user inputs via a web based form and 1) creates a MS Word document and 2) merges the users content into the form via inline tags that are on the .docx file.

Merge tags are placed between <# #> symbols.   I'll attached some screenshots to illustrate what this is.

Basically, the .docx file is my expression builder (aka where I put the xpath tags).  I'll attach some screenshots to better explain this.

Comment: I thought something like this would work, but I'm getting a 'has invalid token error'.  

<# <Content Select="sum(//AddPart_Container/Part(./DirectPrice_unformatted * ./QtyHardware_unformatted))" /> #>

Comment: Your expression is syntactically invalid and also references elements that aren't present in your example XML

Comment: every new step in your path expression needs a `/` before it, but your final step is missing that. Also, the `./` in your final subexpressions is redundant)

Comment: @ConalTuohy Actually, this can be achieved directly, without any `for`  expression.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev yes indeed, but I suggested a `for` expression because personally I think that in this case the more verbose form is more readable and intelligble for those with less experience in XPath.

Comment: @ConalTuohy Maybe you are right and it is all a matter of personal taste, but I like short and concise expressions. Without attempting to generalize that this is always better, I believe that in this particular case the shorter expression is not less readable (but actually on the contrary!)  because it has less "moving parts"  (like `$part in //Part`) and thus has less complexity, therefore greater and easier readability and understandability. Thanks for providing an equally good solution to this nice XPath problem!

Comment: Cheers @DimitreNovatchev I appreciate that. I agree the expression with a function call as a step is more concise. I considered suggesting that at the time, but I thought the longer and more explicit expression was slightly more accessible to people with less XPath experience since it's more similar to how you'd write such a thing in other languages. Additionally, I thought if I was going to introduce _one_ new idea, the more general form (a `for` expression) would be more useful to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple XPath 2.0 expression -- no `for` expression is needed:

***`sum( Part/(round(DirectPrice * Qty div 12 * 100) div 100))`***

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

When this transformation:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "sum( Part/(round(DirectPrice * Qty div 12 * 100) div 100))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is applied on the provided XML document:

```xml
<AddPart_Container displayName="Add Sensor(s)" displayValue="Add Sensor(s)">
    <Part displayName="Part (Sensor 02)" displayValue="Part (Sensor 02)">
        <PartCategory>Hardware</PartCategory>
        <PartName>Wireless Enterprise Vibration Sensor V3 (1 MP per)</PartName>
        <PartNumber>PR55-61E</PartNumber>
        <Cost>366.95</Cost>
        <DirectPrice>492.95</DirectPrice>
        <Qty>200</Qty>
    </Part>
    <Part displayName="Part (Sensor 04)" displayValue="Part (Sensor 04)">
        <PartCategory>Hardware</PartCategory>
        <PartName>Wireless 3 Channel Current Sensor - 0 to 100 (3 MP per)</PartName>
        <PartNumber>PR55-26C</PartNumber>
        <Cost>337.94</Cost>
        <DirectPrice>492.95</DirectPrice>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
    </Part>
</AddPart_Container>
```

the XPath expression is evaluated and the correct, expected result of this evaluation is output:

```
8626.62
```

**Explanation**:

Only few people know and use the fact that an axis step (of a path expression) can be a function call. This is exactly what this solution uses.

***See these rules***:

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-StepExpr
2. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-FilterExpr
3. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-PrimaryExpr
4. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-FunctionCall